# Django validate answer for specific question

Tags: django, django-forms

Overview:
    I want to build a Question-Answer website, where the user has to enter the correct answer for each question. I have made 3 models for this:

```
class ProblemSet(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)

class Problem(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    problem_set = models.ForeignKey(ProblemSet, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    question = models.TextField()
    solution = models.TextField()

class Solve(models.Model):
    username = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    problem_set = models.ForeignKey(ProblemSet, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    problem_id = models.ForeignKey(Problem, on_delete= models.CASCADE)
```

In solve model, if there is any entry that means that particular user has solved that problem_id.
So, I have utilized the generic Form View:

```
class IndexView(FormView):
    form_class = ProblemForm
    template_name = 'home/index.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('index')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(IndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            inner_qs = "fetch ids that are solved from Solve model"

            problem_obj = Problem.objects\
                            .exclude(id__in=inner_qs)\
                            .order_by('id').first()

        else:
            #do something

        context['question'] = problem_obj.question
        return context
```

The problem form is:

```
from django import forms

class ProblemForm(forms.Form):
    solution = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput())
```

How do I validate that the user is inputting the correct answer? I do get the value of **solution** field in def form_valid(self, form) function but how should I deal with it? Should i pass question_id in context and query the database in form_valid, or should i pass solution itself to context and access context data in form_valid() method to prevent double query but in this method I am not sure if this is secure as I don't want solution to be passed to client.

Is there any elegant way of doing this?

P.S. After user entered solution is compared to the one in database for that question, I add an entry in the Solve table denoting that this particular user has solved the question id.

Comment: I would do an javascript AJAX request. If you pass the solution to the page with the question the user can just inspect the page source to get the correct answer. If you care about that, if the user is on the honor system, this may not be as big of a concern.

Comment: Two options: 1. Add the `problem_id` as a hidden input field to the form (you can override `get_initial()` to pre-populate the field) so it's submitted with he answer. The user can manipulate it if he wants, but I don't see any benefit for user, ie. no security issue. 2. Since the `problem_id` doesn't change if the user didn't solve the problem, you can just fetch it again in the `form_valid` case. To avoid fetching it multiple times (you need it in get_context_data), create a new method `get_problem` and assign the value to `self` so it returns it if it's already defined or fetches it.

Comment: @dirkgroten Looks like that is the only option... I was thinking to avoid querying Problem table again in form_valid() function.

Comment: @Waterbyte you have to query both for the GET and for the POST, regardless the option you choose. Those are two separate HTTP requests anyway, in principle (as your code is concerned) unrelated to each other. But you only need to query **once** per request.

Comment: @dirkgroten yes, but i don't want to query Problem table in POST request, only Solve table. And also i don't want to pass solution to the page as Mikeh suggested.

Comment: That's not possible, you **have to query Problem table** on a POST request, how else can you get the solution? Alternatively you could _serialize_ the `problem` in the GET request and save it to the session, to retrieve it in your POST request, but that doesn't make any difference in terms of db hits since the session is stored in the db.

Comment: @dirkgroten What if i do  context['solution'] = problem_obj.solution in IndexView and then access context data in form_valid() function? Is this secure or recommended?

Comment: sure, you can do `context = self.get_context_data(...)` in `form_valid()` and then access `context['solution']`. But that still means you're querying the db in your POST request. And I wouldn't add things in context that you're not rendering in your template (not that it matters in terms of security, the context is only used in the back-end and your users never see it), that's why I suggested creating a separate method that you call both in `get_context_data()` and in `form_valid()` to fetch the `problem`.

Comment: @dirkgroten Thank you. Got to know a lot of things. Can you kindly add your comment to answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FormView` is processing two separate requests: First the GET request when the student fetches the form with a question to answer. Then the POST request when the student submits her answer to the question.

Now HTTP is stateless so somehow you need to keep track of the question that was presented in the first request so you know which question was answered when receiving the POST request.

The easiest way I would say is to actually include the `question_id` in the form itself, as a hidden input field. There's not real security issue here: The `question_id` can be manipulated by the student even though it's hidden, but what's the point?

So this is what I would do:

- Add `problem` as a `ModelChoiceField` with a `HiddenInput` widget to your `ProblemForm`.

  ```
  problem = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Problem.objects.all(), widget=forms.HiddenInput())
  ```
- Set an initial value for the `problem` in the `get_inital()` method of your `IndexView`:

  ```
  def get_problem(self):  # use also in get_context_data() to add the question
      if hasattr(self, 'problem'):
          return self.problem
      if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
          inner_qs = "fetch ids that are solved from Solve model"
          self.problem = Problem.objects\
                          .exclude(id__in=inner_qs)\
                          .order_by('id').first()
          return self.problem

  def get_initial(self):
      initial = super().get_initial()
      initial['problem'] = self.get_problem()}
      return initial
  ```
- When the form gets submitted and is valid, you'll see that `form.cleaned_data['problem']` is the submitted problem. So you can use that in the `form_valid()` method:

  ```
  def form_valid(self, form):
      problem = form.cleaned_data['problem']
      # check that it hasn't been solved by the user already
      if problem.answer == form.cleaned_data['solution']:
          # create solve object for the user
      return redirect(...)
  ```

The alternative would be to not include it in the form but refetch the `problem` in `form_valid` (note that the `problem` is fetched in the above method as well, when the form maps the submitted `problem_id` to the actual `problem` instance to populate its `cleaned_data`).

Comment: Cool, I was able to implement my solution after following this post. For point number 1, i added this in problem form :   **problem = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Problem.objects.all(), widget=forms.HiddenInput())**